# Typo3 8.7: trying to get crdate from db table returns null

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

In my typo3 8.7 extension I'm trying to get the typo3 standard column `crdate` of the logged in user from my database. My problem now is that my db query returns `null` or 0 depending on which datatype I use for the `crdate`. Obviously the column exists and is filled with int values.

As suggested in other questions here and on other plattforms I 

1. added the crdate to the related `TCA Configuration` and 
2. to the `Model` to make it accessible.

TCA

```
'columns' => array(.....
  'crdate' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:someExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_someExt_domain_model_someModelName.crdate',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'passthrough',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ),
    )
```

Model

```
/**
 * crdate
 *
 * @var integer
 */
protected $crdate = 0;

/**
 * @return int $crdate
 */
public function getCrdate()
{
    return $this->crdate;
}

/**
 * @param int $crdate
 */
public function setCrdate($crdate)
{
    $this->crdate = $crdate;
}
```

Controller

```
$currentUser = $this->relatedRepository->findByEmail($currentUserEmail);

//Now the $currentUser object has all attributes of the table, but as my 
//title 
//states the crdate value still is 0. ( If I use datatype date it returns 
//null)
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache from the install tool after you changed your TCA and Model?

Comment: And probably unrelated, but `'eval' => 'trim'` can be removed in TCA for crdate. This will trim the user input data, but for `'type' => 'passthrough'` there is no user input data for that field, so it's useless.

Comment: Yes I cleared the install cache aswell as both backend end and frontend cache individually. I reactivated the extension multiple times.  None of the above helped. Thanks anyways. (I deleted both `eval and type` from the configuration, thanks for the tip.)

Comment: You do need `'type' => 'passthrough'`. In fact, that should be the only thing you need in `config`. I am currently working on a project which does the same for `tstamp` and that works fine. Can you check if your TCA is loaded correctly? You can do this in the backend under "System" > "Configuration" and selecting "$GLOBALS['TCA']" in the top select box.

Comment: @RudyGnodde thanks a lot. The TCA configuration was not loaded correctly as I could figure because of your tip. There was another TCA configuration for this DB Table in another Extension which was used instead.
Thanks a lot, if you write an answer providing the same information how to debug Globals TCA I will accept it as the correct answer if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently working on a project which does the same for tstamp and that works fine. Can you check if your TCA is loaded correctly? You can do this in the backend under "System" > "Configuration" and selecting "$GLOBALS['TCA']" in the top select box.

Unrelated to this problem, you only need `'type' => 'passthrough'` in your TCA config for crdate. `size` and `eval` are only needed if the user can input data for the field.